# Is the received SMS from Google with a code genuine?

Tags: security, sms, google

I just received an SMS, the phone shows that the sender is "Google"
it says:

> .Google (some Arabic) G-123131231 (some code basically).

Could this actually be Google?
Why was it sent to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe someone is trying to login to your Google account, and Google is sending you the 2fa code. As long as you're not logging in yourself, ignore the message.

You may also want to change your password, just to be safe.

And it is recommended to check the list of logged-on devices.

Comment: And it is recommended to check the list of logged-on devices [Google My Devices](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity).

Comment: @Robert Good point, added.